# Current Word document's file location

Tags: microsoft-word

I have checked `File > Info` menu in MSWord 2010. There is not such thing as current doc location in the properties.

This completely describes my problem, including what I have already tried. Something is wrong with SO quality standards. They are formal and do not let to ask brief and clear questions.

Comment: Uhm, what? And welcome to [su] not [so], that place is way to spammy.

Comment: Also to SU, we like nice and clear question. Best guess atm is that you are trying to find the on-disk file location for a word file which you already opened. Which is easy. Close word. `locate` it (or search in windows) or dozens of other solutions. Or first save it in a known place so you know you can find it back.

Comment: What is `locate`? Is MSWord really so bad in telling me the opened file location that the easiest way to know it to search through the whole disk or memorize the address on a sheet of paper?

Comment: Locate is the command you would use on OSX, a BSD ro a linux. It stores file locations in a database. Windows search (with indexing) the the windows variant of this. (You did not specify if you used word on OSX or word on windows, so I added both search options).

Comment: The location is in the "info" of the "File" tab, under the "Related documents", there is a "open file location" icon; when you hover the mouse pointer over the icon a tooltip with the location of the current file shows up.

Comment: Your question doesn't completely define your problem.  Is this an existing file you opened in Word? A new file that you are creating but haven't yet saved?  Is auto-save turned on?  Is it a document you're creating and you have already saved it?

Answer (score 0):

MSWord does not display file location when doc is repaired. Just close the doc and open it again. The file path will be available in the `File > Info`.

Comment: You're question doesn't say anything about the file being repaired.

Comment: @fixer1234 My question does not tell about other 100500 mln properties of my document.